# Why is my Accordion closing animation not firing? It opens (with animation) but closes without animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mertakus/1yowtb0s/5/) of my problem (Click the image next to the 'Werknemers' or 'Verzuimdossiers').

I got a sidebar in which some items have subcontent and some don't. So I made an accordion with subnav items. The problem is that the opening animation works fine. However, the closing animation is not being fired.

What could be the issue here?

**Code for reference**

```js
openSubnav = (evt, subNavName) => {
  let i, subnavContent, subnavLinks;

  //Check if the current accordion is clicked again to close it.
  const subNav = document.getElementById(subNavName)
  if (getComputedStyle(subNav).display === 'block') {
    subNav.style.display = 'none'
    evt.currentTarget.className = evt.currentTarget.className.replace(" subnav-isActive", "");
    subNav.style.maxHeight = null;
    return
  }
  //hide alle subnav content
  subnavContent = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-content");
  for (i = 0; i < subnavContent.length; i++) {
    subnavContent[i].style.display = "none";

  }
  //delete the subnav-isActive class
  subnavLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-item");
  for (i = 0; i < subnavLinks.length; i++) {
    subnavLinks[i].className = subnavLinks[i].className.replace(" subnav-isActive", "");
  }
  //Display the content
  subNav.style.display = "block";
  //Add the subnav-isActive class
  evt.currentTarget.className += " subnav-isActive";

  //If there currently is a max-height on the element, delete it.
  if (subNav.style.maxHeight) {
    subNav.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
  subNav.style.maxHeight = subNav.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  -o-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}

.icon-container {
  width: 60px; 
  height: 50px; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

/* .sidebar:hover {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
} */

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #8dc4d9;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  /* width:60px; */
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
  transition:width .05s linear;
}

.sidebar>ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar li {
  width:250px;
}

.sidebar li>span {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

.sidebar .nav-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 250px breed totaal - 60px breed icoon = 190 */
  width: 190px;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown img {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown.subnav-isActive img {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar li:hover>span {
  background-color:#76abbf;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  /* 17px omdat de afbeelding 24x24 is en de breedte van de sidebar 60px. 
     Met de afbeelding houd je dus 17px aan beiden kanten over. */
  padding: 10px 17px;
  background-color:#76abbf;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.content {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}

.preview {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Sidebar</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li class="user">
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/user32.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Mijn account
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/bureaublad24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Dashboard
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="has-subnav">
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/werknemers24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Werknemers
            </span>
            <span class="nav-dropdown subnav-item" onclick="openSubnav(event, 'Werknemers')">
              <img src="./icons24/DropdownArrow16.png">
            </span>
          </span>
          <ul id="Werknemers" class="subnav-content">
            <li>kaas</li>
            <li>brood</li>
            <li>eieren</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/verzuimdossiers24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Verzuimdossiers
            </span>
            <span class="nav-dropdown subnav-item" onclick="openSubnav(event, 'Verzuimdossiers')">
              <img src="./icons24/DropdownArrow16.png">
            </span>
          </span>
          <ul id="Verzuimdossiers" class="subnav-content">
            <li>boter</li>
            <li>friet</li>
            <li>pasta</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/trajecten24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Trajecten
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/projecten24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Projecten
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
      Preview
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to **set timeout** before the `display: none` so it has time to prosecute the closing animation.

Like in this code:

```
  const subNav = document.getElementById(subNavName)
  if (getComputedStyle(subNav).display === 'block') {
    evt.currentTarget.className = evt.currentTarget.className.replace(" subnav-isActive", "");
    subNav.style.maxHeight = null;
    setTimeout(function(){subNav.style.display = 'none';}, 100);
    return
  }
```

Here you have the right code complete (idk why, but you need to expand the snippet to see it working, click on **Run code snippet and then Full page** link):

```js
openSubnav = (evt, subNavName) => {
  let i, subnavContent, subnavLinks;

  //Check if the current accordion is clicked again to close it.
  const subNav = document.getElementById(subNavName)
  if (getComputedStyle(subNav).display === 'block') {
    evt.currentTarget.className = evt.currentTarget.className.replace(" subnav-isActive", "");
    subNav.style.maxHeight = null;
    setTimeout(function(){subNav.style.display = 'none';}, 100);
    return
  }
  //hide alle subnav content
  subnavContent = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-content");
  for (i = 0; i < subnavContent.length; i++) {
    subnavContent[i].style.display = "none";

  }
  //delete the subnav-isActive class
  subnavLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-item");
  for (i = 0; i < subnavLinks.length; i++) {
    subnavLinks[i].className = subnavLinks[i].className.replace(" subnav-isActive", "");
  }
  //Display the content
  subNav.style.display = "block";
  //Add the subnav-isActive class
  evt.currentTarget.className += " subnav-isActive";

  //If there currently is a max-height on the element, delete it.
  if (subNav.style.maxHeight) {
    subNav.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
  subNav.style.maxHeight = subNav.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  -o-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}

.icon-container {
  width: 60px; 
  height: 50px; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

/* .sidebar:hover {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
} */

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #8dc4d9;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  /* width:60px; */
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
  transition:width .05s linear;
}

.sidebar>ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar li {
  width:250px;
}

.sidebar li>span {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

.sidebar .nav-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 250px breed totaal - 60px breed icoon = 190 */
  width: 190px;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown img {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-dropdown.subnav-isActive img {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.user {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar li:hover>span {
  background-color:#76abbf;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  /* 17px omdat de afbeelding 24x24 is en de breedte van de sidebar 60px. 
     Met de afbeelding houd je dus 17px aan beiden kanten over. */
  padding: 10px 17px;
  background-color:#76abbf;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.content {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}

.preview {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Sidebar</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li class="user">
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/user32.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Mijn account
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/bureaublad24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Dashboard
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="has-subnav">
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/werknemers24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Werknemers
            </span>
            <span class="nav-dropdown subnav-item" onclick="openSubnav(event, 'Werknemers')">
              <img src="./icons24/DropdownArrow16.png">
            </span>
          </span>
          <ul id="Werknemers" class="subnav-content">
            <li>kaas</li>
            <li>brood</li>
            <li>eieren</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/verzuimdossiers24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Verzuimdossiers
            </span>
            <span class="nav-dropdown subnav-item" onclick="openSubnav(event, 'Verzuimdossiers')">
              <img src="./icons24/DropdownArrow16.png">
            </span>
          </span>
          <ul id="Verzuimdossiers" class="subnav-content">
            <li>boter</li>
            <li>friet</li>
            <li>pasta</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/trajecten24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Trajecten
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <img class="nav-icon" src="./icons24/projecten24.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <span class="nav-text">
              Projecten
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
      Preview
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because your animation takes some time to execute, but you assign `display: none` before your animation has any chance to be rendered.